# A statement for convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The following statement is true or false?

Given a convex set $S$ then for any $y \in S$ and $\theta\in[0,1], \theta \in \mathbb R$ there exist $y_1,y_2 \in S, y_1 \ne y, y_2 \ne y$ such that $y=\theta y_1+(1-\theta) y_2.$

Comment: The counterexamples to this statement are called the extreme points of a set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need $S$ convex: just take $y_1 = y_2 = y$.

Comment: Thanks @user7530. What happen if $y_1 \ne y$ and $y_2 \ne y?$

Comment: @user Then it is false: consider a set $S$ containing only one point.

Comment: Thank you @user7530. I further have a question that for any convex set $S$ then $S = \{ \theta y_1 + (1-\theta) y_2 | \theta \in [0,1], \theta \in \mathbb R, y_1,y_2 \in S \}$. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of a convex set (your expression is not exactly well-formed, but I get what you mean.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe $S \ne \varnothing$ and $S \ne \{a\}$, set with a single element my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is clearly false: just think about a vertex of a square!

By the way, you guys got it wrong: by definition the empty set and a single point are convex set. The latter is indeed an affine set of dimension 0.

A set $S$ is convex iff

$$ \forall x,y \in S \Rightarrow \theta x + (1-\theta)y \in S, \quad  \forall \theta \in [0,1]$$

an it doesn't say that the two point must be different. Otherwise a square would not be a convex set.